# How to convert UIColor to Hexadecimal (web color text string)?

Tags: ios, uikit, uicolor

Is there an easy way to convert `UIColor` to a hexadecimal value ?
Or do we have to get the RGB components with `CGColorGetComponents` and then work it out from there?

e.g `CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)[0] * 256` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would consider using Erica Sadun's UIColor category. It includes a lot of functionality for free, including hex representations. It's pretty easy to use, just add it to whatever class header you're using it in or, add it to the pre-compiled header for ultimate flexibility.
 If you're adding to the pre-compiled header, do so similar to something like this:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "UIColor-Expanded.h"
#endif
```

Then You can use it like so `NSLog(@"%@", [myColor hexStringFromColor]);`

GitHub link to the UIColor category: https://github.com/erica/uicolor-utilities

ArsTechnica article about it: http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/02/iphone-development-accessing-uicolor-components.ars

Answer (score 10):

I also had to convert a UIColor to its hex components.

As already pointed out by lewiguez there is a very good category at [github](https://github.com/erica/uicolor-utilities) that does all that stuff.

But because I wanted to learn how it is done I made my own simple implementation for RGB colours.

```
+ (NSString*)colorToWeb:(UIColor*)color
{
    NSString *webColor = nil;

    // This method only works for RGB colors
    if (color &&
        CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor) == 4)
    {
        // Get the red, green and blue components
        const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);

        // These components range from 0.0 till 1.0 and need to be converted to 0 till 255
        CGFloat red, green, blue;
        red = roundf(components[0] * 255.0);
        green = roundf(components[1] * 255.0);
        blue = roundf(components[2] * 255.0);

        // Convert with %02x (use 02 to always get two chars)
        webColor = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02x%02x%02x", (int)red, (int)green, (int)blue];
    }

    return webColor;
}
```

All feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Other than the widely used string based solution, here's a hex (integer) based solution. Usage:

```
UIColor* color = lf_rgb(0x120aef);
log(@"color %.6x", color.hex_rgb);
```

And you'll get "color 120aef". I'll put these code in https://github.com/superarts/LCategory, or you can copy-paste into your own code bank too:

```
#define lf_rgb(rgbValue)    [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@interface UIColor (lc_rgb)
- (NSInteger)hex_rgb;
@end

@implementation UIColor (lc_rgb)
- (NSInteger)hex_rgb
{
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    BOOL result = [self getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
    //  log(@"rgba: %f, %f, %f, %f", r * 255, g * 255, b * 255, a * 255);
    if ((result == NO) || (a != 1.0f))
        return -1;
    return 
        (NSInteger)(r * 255) * 256 * 256 + 
        (NSInteger)(g * 255) * 256 +
        (NSInteger)(b * 255) * 1;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, as far as I know, any built in solution.
Note however, that you should multiply by `255` instead of `256`.

Getting an hexadecimal representation is an easy task, so you won't have many troubles to build the string manually.

```
NSLog(@"%X%X%X", redInteger, greenInteger, blueInteger);
```

Comment: I think that's a clever way to do it. Since the component returns a float number, how can you convert it accurately to an integer? e.g for a purplish color: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.548638 0.554697 1 1

Comment: you will have integers by casting or rounding the result, tested RGB 0.548638 0.554697 1, truncating, rounding, giving me each time *the same* purplish color.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your truncate and rounding? Maybe I am rounding too high but I'm always getting 1 and the %X%X%X comes out as 111

Comment: @fes - (NSUInteger)(0.548638 * 255.0) == 139

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do did it with Swift 3:

```
extension UIColor {
    var hex:String{
        get{
            var red:CGFloat = 0
            var blue:CGFloat = 0
            var green:CGFloat = 0
            var alpha:CGFloat = 0

            self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
            let rgb:Int = (Int)(red*255)<<16 | (Int)(green*255)<<8 | (Int)(blue*255)<<0
            return String.localizedStringWithFormat("#%06x", rgb)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can make it a method. I just like how `color.hex` looks vs `color.hex()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Swift 5 solution, as extensions to UIColor, to convert  UIColor object to a hex color string of RGB (#RRGGBB) form or RGBA (#RRGGBBAA) format ,and also use either format and create a UIColor, with option to provide an alpha argument with #RRGGBB form as non-default value of 1.0 for alpha.

I started with @boidkan's answer then searched around for other solutions on S.O. and then refined and optimized them to a solution I could live with, and tested them in playground.

```
/* Returns UIColor as "#RRGGBB" (hex string) */
var hexRGB : String {
    func comp(_ value: CGFloat, _ byteShift: Int = 0) -> Int { return Int(value * 0xff) << (byteShift * 8) }
    var r = CGFloat(0), b = CGFloat(0), g = CGFloat(0), a = CGFloat(0)
    getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return String(format: "#%6.6X", comp(r, 2) | comp(g, 1) | comp(b))
}

/* Returns UIColor as "#RRGGBBAA" (hex string) */
var hexRGBA : String {
    func comp(_ value: CGFloat, _ byteShift: Int = 0) -> Int { return Int(value * 0xff) << (byteShift * 8) }
    var r = CGFloat(0), b = CGFloat(0), g = CGFloat(0), a = CGFloat(0)
    getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
    return String(format: "#%8.8X", comp(r, 3) | comp(g, 2) | comp(b, 1) | comp(a))
}

/*
 * Returns UIColor object given input of the one of the following formats, where:
 *
 *       RR = Red component as hex value    00-FF
 *       GG = Green component as hex value  00-FF
 *       BB = Blue component as hex value   00-FF
 *       AA = Alpha componenet as hex value 00-FF
 *        a = Alpha component as 0.00 - 1.00 (a is optional, defaults to 1.0)
 *
 *       ("RRGGBB"[, a]),   ("#RRGGBB"[, a]), ("RRGGBBAA"), or ("#RRGGBBA")
 */
convenience init(hexRGBA: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    let cleanHex = hexRGBA.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
                          .replacingOccurrences(of: #"[^0-9a-fA-F]"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)

    assert(cleanHex.count == 6 || cleanHex.count == 8, "Bad RGB/RGBA value")
    
    var rgbIntValue: UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string:cleanHex).scanHexInt64(&rgbIntValue)
    let hh1 = CGFloat( Double((rgbIntValue & 0xff000000) >> 24)  / 255.0)
    let hh2 = CGFloat( Double((rgbIntValue & 0x00ff0000) >> 16)  / 255.0)
    let hh3 = CGFloat( Double((rgbIntValue & 0x0000ff00) >> 8)   / 255.0)
    let hh4 = CGFloat( Double((rgbIntValue & 0x000000ff)         / 255.0)
    if (cleanHex.count == 8) {
        self.init(red:  hh1, green: hh2, blue: hh3, alpha: hh4)
        return
    }
    self.init(red: hh2, green: hh3, blue: hh4, alpha: alpha) /* RGB + A */
}
```